# my sql insert query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting userId.It is displaying correct but inserting **0** in spite of actual userId. mycode-

```
If(! empty($userIDToCheck) || $userIDToCheck != '' )
{
echo $userIDToCheck;  
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pnpdb`.`ruser` (`userid`) VALUES ('$userIDToCheck');";  
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Done";  
}
```

**Output :** `pi203713 Done`

**But is database it is inserting "0"**???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what datatype is the userid column in ruser?

Comment: this is an answer because I made a datatype mismatch mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your variable's value is **not** zero?

Perhaps there's an assignment mistake further up your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pnpdb`.`ruser` (`userid`) VALUES ('".$userIDToCheck."');";
```